# Spring web application using spring-integration-dsl-groovy throwing an error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/integration/Message"

Tags: spring-mvc, groovy, spring-integration

I am trying to run a simple spring web application with **spring-integration-dsl-groovy**, but i am getting an below error

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler
>   processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/integration/Message

Can anyone help me?

Here is my code

```
@RestController
class SampleController{

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    String start(){
        def builder = new IntegrationBuilder()
        def flow = builder.messageFlow{
            transform {String payload -> "Welcome $payload - Powered by Groovy !!!"}
            handle{ println payload }
        }


        return flow.sendAndReceive("to Spring MVC ")
    }
}
```

Added all required dependecies, including spring mvc, groovy, spring integration

```
compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:$groovyVersion"
compile "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:$springIntegrationVersion"
compile "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-dsl-groovy-core:$springInegrationDslGroovyVersion"
```

Comment: What's is the version of `spring-integration-core` and `spring-integration-dsl-groovy-core`? Anyway, just remove `spring-integration-core` and try again.

Comment: springIntegrationVersion = '4.1.4.RELEASE'
springInegrationDslGroovyVersion = '1.0.+'

Comment: Thanks @BrunoCésar, your question gave hint to resolve. Spring-integration-dsl-groovy-core 1.0 is very old version. I upgraded spring integration-dsl-groovy-core to 1.1 and its working.

Comment: Maybe delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

spring-integration-dsl-groovy-core 1.0.0 is not compatible with Spring Integration 4.1.4. spring-integration-dsl-groovy-core 1.1.0 is latest version available and its compatible with Spring Integration 4.1.4